# how to fix TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67 in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5.2 and got above error when I try to submit form data.

My blade file is this.

```
 @extends('layouts.app1')

    @section('title')
    <h3>Board of Directors</h3>
    @endsection


    @section('content')


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector : "textarea",
    plugins : ["advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor", "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen", "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"],
    toolbar : "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
  }); 
</script>

    <form action="/create" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
      <textarea name='body'class="form-control">{{  old('body')  }}</textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name='publish' class="btn btn-success" value = "Publish"/>
      <input type="submit" name='save' class="btn btn-default" value = "Save Draft" />
    </form>
    @endsection
```

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a CSRF field inside your form tags

`{!! csrf_field() !!}`

Comment: Is it running locally or on a server? on the server you should check if you have set the right permissions for the folders: [Directory Permissions Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation) 
Otherwise you can always try to generate a new key `php artisan generate key`

Comment: it is running in localhost

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you define a HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the csrf_field helper to generate the token field:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `'domain' => 'to your domain'` in your `config/session.php` file

Answer (score 0):

Another posible aproach and mostly if you are building an API with no views and you are receiving this error is to put the route(s) outside the middleware.

In my case I wanted to avoid this error for all my api routes `'api/*'`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'api/*',
    ];
}
```

You can locate the file at `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

You should be aware that you can do this for web routes too, it's not the common practice but there are some cases where you don't have other option, as Laravel Doc says: [csrf-excluding-uris](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)